# Wordpress cannot access files

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I created a new theme with index.php, style.css and screenshot.png. Later on created header.php,footer, menu ect. The problem is I cannot access those. I can open index.php,style.css and screenshot.png with no problems. All the files have permissions 755, checked x10.

Examples by URL:

- http://mydevelops.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/index.php <-opens
- http://mydevelops.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css <- opens
- http://mydevelops.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/header.php <-fobidden
- http://mydevelops.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/footer.php <-fobidden

Error message:

> You don't have permission to access /wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/header.php on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: http://mysite.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/footer.php didn't show a forbidden, it showed a 404 *"The requested URL /wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/footer.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."* Same thing for http://mysite.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/header.php just as you state, just not a "forbidden". Double check your paths.

Comment: Plus, http://mysite.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/index.php that's a 404 also, as is http://mysite.lv/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/style.css and http://mysite.lv/wp-content/ for that matter. Check your installation too.

Comment: Are you sure you've expanded and uploaded your site??? The only **working** content is http://http://mysite.lv/ which echos "soon..."

Comment: Sorry, turns out there is sutch site as mysite.lv, that was like an example. Edited

Comment: *"Oops! Google Chrome could not find mydevelops.lv"* So, your site is either not live, or you haven't set any nameservers for it.

Comment: Yes, thats not my actual site, I wont put it here its not secure. I have provided all info in description.

Comment: Well, as I already stated. Double check your installation and see what you can find in the WordPress documentation.

Comment: Personally, I would start by reverting to one of the WordPress "default" themes (TwentyTwelve, for example) -> Delete your theme folders -> Re-upload your ORIGINAL theme (test working) -> Create a CHILD THEME -> Enable the child theme -> duplicate your original theme footer.php into your child theme folder -> edit this file. See how you go with this. When you upload your custom .php files leave their permissions alone. They should be set to the required permissions when you upload them. WP has been tried and tested for many years - you "shouldn't" need to mess with any permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the files owner and group as well as the permissions.

Comment: Setting all those premissions to 777 does not help

Comment: But have you checked the owner and group ?

Comment: I have owner premissions,group premissions and public. All three have  checkboxes read write and execute, I have checked them all.